# Multiple mc with dynamic name to show on stage on random place and click them away doesn't work

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, random, timer

I want to make a little game. You have to hit a red circle within 3 seconds. The next circle is showing up after another second so you have to hit them fast.

I found a way to make a dynamic variable. Tt seems to working, but the `wennduklikst Eventlistener` at the end of the code is not working anymore now. But it should. Do you know why it's not working?

I attach my code.
i thought this is the the most efficient way but I'm not sure about it.

```
var count:Number = 0
var _mc:Array = new Array();
for(var i:int = 0; i<=100; ++i)
{
     var _mc0:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
     this.addChild(_mc0);
     // now add your square object to our Array
     _mc.push(_mc0);
}
//var _mc0:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var _errortimer:Array = new Array();
for(var i2:int = 0; i2<=100; ++i2)
{
     var _errortimer0:Timer = new Timer(3000,1);
     //addChild(_errorTimer0);
     // now add your square object to our Array
     _errortimer.push(_errortimer0);
}
//var errorTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000,1);
// 3000 = Zeit zwischen zwei Timeraufrufen in Millisekunden
// 0 = Anzahl der Wiederholungen (0 = unendlich oft)
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);

// Event listeners:
myTimer.addEventListener("timer", myTimerAction);
//myTimer.addEventListener("timerComplete", myTimerComplete);
myTimer.start();

// Event handlers:
function myTimerAction(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    trace(event.target.currentCount+" mal ausgelöst.");
    // der Code
    // der alle x Millisekunden
    // ausgeführt wird.

    // Event listeners:
    _errortimer[0].addEventListener("timer", errorTimerAction);
    _errortimer[0].addEventListener("errortimerComplete", errorTimerComplete);
    _errortimer[0].start();

    // Event handlers:;
    function errorTimerAction(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        myTimer.stop();
        ergebnis.text = (count+" hast du geschafft");
    }

    function errorTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        trace("Timer ,,wird entfernt.");
        _errortimer[0].removeEventListener("timer", errorTimerAction);
        _errortimer[0].removeEventListener("timerComplete", errorTimerComplete);
    }

function CustomCircle(xInput:Number,yInput:Number,rInput:Number,colorInput:uint)
    {
        _mc[0].graphics.beginFill(colorInput);
        _mc[0].graphics.drawCircle(xInput, yInput, rInput);
    }
    CustomCircle(-35,35, 60, 0xFF3A00);
_mc[0].addChild

        var yrandomNum:Number = yrandomRange(70,947);

    //y axenwert zufällig
    function yrandomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number
    {
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
    }

    var xrandomNum:Number = xrandomRange(70,570);

    //x axenwert zufällig    
    function xrandomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number
    {
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
    }

    _mc[0].x = xrandomNum;
    _mc[0].y = yrandomNum;
    _mc[0].name = "mcButton";
    //addChild(_mc);
}

/**
function myTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    // Es ist immer eine gute Idee, Event listener
    // zu entfernen, wenn sie nicht mehr benötigt
    // werden:
    trace("Timer wird entfernt.");
    myTimer.removeEventListener("timer", myTimerAction);
    myTimer.removeEventListener("timerComplete", myTimerComplete);
}

**/    
_mc[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wennduklickst);
function wennduklickst(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    _mc[0].removeChild
    _errortimer[0].stop();
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You had some severe formatting issues in your code for which I offered an edit. I suggest that you check that all the indentation is still intact. I also suggest that you translate your code comments to English.

Answer (score 0):

Your listener works well but you should write:

```
removeChild(_mc[0]);
```